# Can anyone explain why this function is not working in mariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

Can anyone help with the below code? Im new to mariaDB and am struggling to create the function. Im not even sure if im highliting and executing it right. Whatever I do, I get many errors.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION singerExperience(
    experience DECIMAL(10,2)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE singerExperience VARCHAR(20);

    IF hours > 4000 THEN
        SET singerExperience = 'PLATINUM';
    ELSEIF (hours >= 4000 AND 
            hours <= 1000) THEN
        SET singerExperience = 'GOLD';
    ELSEIF hours < 1000 THEN
        SET singerExperience = 'SILVER';
    END IF;
    RETURN (singerExperience);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT singer_id, singerExperience(experience)
FROM experiencelog
ORDER BY singer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the parameter `experience` to `hours` (or variable hours to experience) the function should work.

However why do you need a function, if you can handle that within the statement?

```
SELECT singer_id, 
case experience < 1000 THEN 'SILVER' WHEN experience < 4000 THEN 'GOLD' ELSE 'PLATINUM' END
FROM experiencelog
ORDER BY singer_id;
```